# How to disable row sorting in dgv?

Tags: windows, forms, sorting, row

How to disable row sorting by user (so by clicking on column headers) in data grid view in windows forms?

I know you can disable column sorting, but I can't find any method that disables row sorting. I could use a hidden field with the correct index. So even if the user reorders rows, it will be saved correctly in the databank (by reordering List by hidden indexfield). But that seems kinda messy. There has to be a build in method or property for this, right?

Thanks in regards

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of tricky you should implement the column_added event :

```
Private Sub DGV_ColumnAdded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewOrganigramme.ColumnAdded
        DGV.Columns(e.Column.DisplayIndex).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.